# Set Text 0 in EditText when its empty and remove that 0 when user starts typing value in EditText in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, validation, input, android-edittext

When EditText is empty set text 0 and When user starts Typing values in EditText remove that 0 in Android kotlin

I have Tried Textwatcher afterTextChanged and implemented multiple condition but none of them is working...

P.S

android:hint="0" won't help bcz it will display text but won't fill editText and this EditText values are used for calculations so It must be 0 when its empty

Comment: What for? Just set tge value to 0 and if user want to change, s/he will delete old value and put new one. There's no point of 0 being treated special way. This smells like bad UX for me. Why not use hint feature if EditText if you want to give user a cue?

Comment: Buddy putting hint won't help as It won't fill editText and I have to use this EditText values in calculations So it Can't be empty...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tired hint?. I'm positive this is the one you are looking for.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Enter your text here"/>
```

or you can do it like that in code.

```
val editText = findViewById(R.id.editText) as EditText 
editText.hint = "Enter your text here"
```

Comment: I have tried putting hint but thing is I cannnot keep it empty as I have to use this edit Text value in calculations so It must be ZERO when its empty and hint will just display text but It won't fill editText so This won't work

Comment: then add it as text? it will be always zero. you can use get text to get the editText value and use it. Intents or shared preference work if you want to use it  in another activity. Note: you original question didn't include that

Answer (score 1):

> used for calculations so It must be 0 when its empty

First, it's either empty or `0`. Can't be both. So why not simply put the `0` as a default value and disallow having test edit empty? Why is empty/'0' even treated special way at all - it just complicates things here for you and help swith nothing.

As I already stated in the comment above, the approach described in your question (with watchers etc) looks like bad U/X and to me it looks like you try to fix the problem that does not really exist. Then I realize that if you want to make user life easier when entering new value in that text edit (so s/he does not need to delete old value first) then all you need really is to select the content on focus, so any user input overwrite old content automatically + this behavior will be clear to the user (s/he will see the select) in advance. So for me, all you should do is to add

```xml
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

to your `EditText` element and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

```
val calculationTextWatcher: TextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun befor`enter code here`eTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                if (holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.text.toString().isNullOrBlank()) {
                    holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.setText("0")
                    holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.setSelection(1)
                }
                if (holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.text.toString().length >= 2 && holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.text.toString()
                        .startsWith("0")
                ) {
                    val subStr =
                        holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.text.toString().substring(1)
                    holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.setText(subStr)
                    holder.binding.tvBagsBuyerAuctionItemAdapter.setSelection(1)
                }
                
            }
        }
```

This works completely fine...!